Changed ownership to host:host for entire SD card and now suffering the consequences
I did something really dumb.
At the root of an SSD card I ran: sudo chown -R root:root . when I should have run: sudo chown -R myusername:myusername . Now I cannot access files/directories for the entire SSD when logged in under myusername
Going into the terminal as sudo root and browsing to the SSD now shows an empty directory.
Results of sudo ls -al :
drwxrwxrwx    3 root root  4096 Feb 11  2023 foo
drwxrwxrwx    2 root root  4096 Nov 28 14:26 fii
drwxr-xr-x    5 root root  4096 Nov 28 14:26 thumb
drwxrwxrwx    2 root root  4096 Nov 28 14:26 fooder
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root    69 Nov 18  2023 datab.vdf
drwx------    2 root root 16384 Dec  6 17:35 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx    2 root root  4096 Nov 28 14:26 meta
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root root  4656 Mar 23  2023 noob.out
drwxrwxrwx    2 root root  4096 Feb 10  2023 nerds


Please edit your question to show us the first 10 lines of: sudo ls -al /path/to/sd/card

This is done - thanks!

Ah, it's just data storage, so simply run the correct chown command. Had this been an installed system on the card, it would require reinstall.

This question is similar to: Change folder permissions and ownership. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OK I'm back in action, sorry the solution was simple and basic...
sudo chown -R myusername:myusername .


Please click the check beside your answer to mark it as accepted.
